# Quotient metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be some set, $(Y, \rho)$ be a metric space and $f:X\to Y$ be some map. Let $d$ be a pseudometric on $X$ defined by $d(x', x'') = \rho(f(x'), f(x''))$ and consider a quotient metric space $\tilde X = X/_d$. Is it true that $\tilde X$ is isomorphic to $f(X)\subseteq Y$?

Comment: Yes, you have an induced isometry $\tilde{f} \colon \tilde{X} \to f(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is isometric. The isometry is given explicitly by $f$ acting on equivalence classes.

The equivalence class $[a] \in \tilde X$ of $a\in X$ is $\{x \in X | d(x,a)=0 \}$. Then $\tilde d([a],[b]):=\inf_{x \in [a], y \in [b]} d(x,y)$ satisfies the conditions of a metric.

Let $a,b \in X$. If $[a]=[b]$ then $\rho(f(a),f(b))=0$ so $f(a)=f(b)$ and we can view $f$ as a well defined map on the quotient space. $f([a])=f([b])$ also implies $[a]=[b]$, so this map is an injection on the quotient space.

Now $\tilde d ([a],[b])= \inf_{x \in [a], y \in [b]} d(x,y) = \inf_{x \in [a], y \in [b]} \rho(f(x),f(y))=\rho(f([a]),f([b]))$ since $f$ is constant on the equivalence classes.

We have a metric preserving injective map, this is an isometry on its image.